# Can you create a main function in the server side of GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to create a "public static void main" function on the server side of a GWT project which could create and call additional threads. Is it possible to do so? Obviously, the function should be called as soon as the project is run, whether or not any sessions are initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side GWT is a normal servlet environment, so you can use the normal servlet init() methods to start any tasks you need.